# How to run Spotify in background?

Tags: 16.04, system-tray, spotify

Like other music players (e.g. Rhythmbox) I want to run Spotify(Spotify version 1.0.49.125.g72ee7853) in background.

But when I close the spotify window, it terminates the program. I have gone through the settings inside it and found this label "Startup and Window Behaviour", but there is nothing under this label. [image: Screenshot Here]

Running `$ spotify --minimized` gives me an error `[0426/014157:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(752)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak`

Is this a known bug Or I'm facing this because I haven't upgraded my account yet? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: setsid spotify doesn't work?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. I get exact same behaviour.

Comment: Nope! Same error. @EODCraftStaff

Comment: Use the Testing repo....[echo deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list]

Comment: Please, 
What Version of Linux are you using ?
Ubuntu 17.04 ?
Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 ?
64 bits ?
Version of your system please

What is the meaning of "runing spotfy in background" for you ?

Comment: That empty settings group is still there a year later

Answer (score 3):

### [It is indeed a bug](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web-Player/Linux-Spotify-client-1-x-now-in-stable/td-p/1300404)

Spotify hasn't, and most likely won't, implement the feature to add Spotify to the tray, so that it would be minimized while still running. The official thread makes reference to the `1.0.23` version of `spotify-client`, but the bug still prevails.

[**Original text**](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web-Player/Linux-Spotify-client-1-x-now-in-stable/td-p/1300404)

> **Known linux specific issues in 1.0.23**
>
> - Improper MPRIS support (there is support since 1.0.13, but limited functionality). Spotify DBus MPRIS2 support not fully working
> - Sometimes crashes when streaming and playing local files (these very likely have more than one root cause)
> - Linux Client crashing (segfault) on certain songs -- Segfaults when playing local files
> - Improper package dependencies for installation outside Ubuntu LTS The return of the libssl trouble on Linux
> - Missing application menu
> - Missing tray icon
> - Minimize (to tray)
>
> **Most of these we want to fix, but others (like missing tray icon) we probably won't.**

Answer (score 1):

*(SEMI) Fixed in the Latest test Version.

```
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

You may have to re-do your Cache folder, I did.
To run minimized use nohup

```
nohup spotify
```

*I just realized I had spotify Window open and running in another work space so what the Op wants is still not achievable.

Comment: Can you add to the answer then, how to clear the cache?

Comment: It's in your Home folder just delete it. I think the only reason I had to do mine is cause I ran some commands as Sudo testing different background apps.

Comment: OP wants to be able to close the Spotify window, but keep Spotify running in the background. How do you achive this with the testing release of Spotify?

Comment: It actually didn't need http:// @M. Becerra to add that repository, maybe that just proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use the AudFree Spotify Music Downloader. It helps you to get lossless Spotify songs on your Pc and transfer them to your apps for being background music. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Spotify will have such an error, which makes us very confused. In fact, there is a way to prevent this error permanently. You can use [DumpMedia](https://www.dumpmedia.com/spotify-music-converter/) to convert and download your Spotify tracks. Then you can play your Spotify tracks in the background. And you don’t need to worry about the sound quality. It will not cause any quality loss. Here are steps to use the tool:

Step 1. Download and Launch the DumpMedia Application
Before you can start using the application, of course, you need to download the software first. After downloading the DumpMedia installer, launch the application by following the steps below for Windows and macOS operating systems.

Step 2. Add Your Spotify Song to the Application
Add the URI of your Spotify song/playlist/album on the search bar or you can drag and drop your files to the application.

Step 3. Choose Your Desired Output Format and Destination Folder
Look for the “Convert all tasks to” text at the top right corner of the interface. Select your desired output format (FLAC, WAV, M4A, or MP3). At the bottom of the interface, click on the Browse button and browse your computer to the desired destination folder of the converted files.

Step 4. Start the Conversion Process
Click the "Convert" button to start the conversion of your Spotify music files. Wait for a few minutes, the conversion will be completed. Now all you need to do is to check out the converted files in your local folder.